# Silverlight stackpanel Orientation Horizontal last element fill to infinite

Tags: silverlight, width, element, stackpanel

In a scenario like this:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Element1/>
     <Element2>
</StackPanel>
```

It possible to stretch last element (Element2) in control list to fit all possible space (like width="*")?

I am forced to use a grid?

Answer (score 3):

The StackPanel content area collapses to fit the children. Stretch in the direction that grows on a StackPanel is only useful for painting the background. It does not affect the children.

Use a grid or a custom container.